# How to convert the number of month in the name abbreviation in Jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, date-formatting

I have a XY Line Chart in JasperReports and I´m using a range in my Chart for display the Months, currently i´m using this configuration and show the values from 1 to 12 in X Line:

[Image of currently chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tkR8.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.class.1" value="net.sf.jasperreports.customizers.axis.DomainAxisCustomizer"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.1.tickUnit" value="1.0"/>
                    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.1.minValue"><![CDATA["1"]]></propertyExpression>
                    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.1.maxValue"><![CDATA["12"]]></propertyExpression>
```

but I need show the abbreviation of the months, like this:

1 - JAN,
2 - FEB,
3 - MAR,
...

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own domain axis customizer like this:

```
public class DomainAxisWithMonthsCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        String[] shortMonths = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();
        SymbolAxis domainAxis = new SymbolAxis("Month",
                IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 12)
                        .mapToObj(m -> m + " - " + shortMonths[m - 1].toUpperCase())
                        .toArray(String[]::new));
        plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
    }
}
```

And use it in your report template:

```
<chart customizerClass="my.project.report.DomainAxisWithMonthsCustomizer">
...
</chart>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer me. Is it possible do this in Tibco Jasper Reports?

Comment: I tested that with JasperSoft Jasper Reports 6.7.0. Which version are you using? That example class must be compiled by `javac`, then create JAR archive and add it to classpath of application where you want to run the report (JasperStudio, your custom application, JasperReports Server).

Comment: The solution works fine, I did some configuration in Jasper to work with java classes, and after applied your solution. Thanks a lot.